# best interfaces for VC++ & openCV code

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, vision

I have win32 C++ code and openCV , and I want to design interfaces to that code.

what is the best implementation for it?

I would lik to use WPF but more websites say it is not supported in VC++ & openCV

cloud you help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

QT is now integrated in OpenCV GUI since 2.x, so I'd say this is the most logical choice.